# Reusing form in two projects loses the images on the toolbar

Tags: image, toolbar

I have a form which I would like to reuse across multiple projects. I add the form into the projects by linking them, therefore have one version with one set of changes which will affect all the projects.

My problem is that the form will display the images in the original project, but in any subsequent projects, the images on the toolbar have disappeared.

Do I have to add the images into the resources (which doesn't seem to work)?

Comment: What language?  Your problem is very vague and unspecific.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. I am using VB.NET